# deepin-terminal: The drop-down menu does not disappear when I click with the left mouse button

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

In the deepin terminal the drop-down menu appears when I click with the right mouse button but it does not disappear when I click with the left mouse button but only by pressing the "Esc" key, why?
I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.3 LTS 64-bit.
If I use Deepin desktop instead of other desktop environments (Gnome Desktop, Cinnamon), the problem doesn't arise.
How to solve the problem regardless of the Desktop environment used?

[image]

Comment: Question should be addressed to https://superuser.com/ community. StackOverflow is for programming-related questions

Comment: Ok, done.
https://superuser.com/questions/1677554